# Imagemagick convert method failure

Tags: ubuntu, imagemagick

I am using imagemagick 6.7.7 on ubuntu 14.04

I am trying to convert image with following command.

`convert a.png -auto-orient -strip -write mpr:a.png +delete`

It fails with this error.

`convert.im6: missing an image filename +delete @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3046`

However it works fine on ubuntu 12.04 with imagemagick 6.6.9

Any idea how to make it work with 6.7.7?

Comment: You cannot write to an mpr file as png. MPR is its own format. You should use just mpr:a, where a is the name of the in-memory file. However, all you are doing is loading the image into memory and removing the input image. MPR is use to save images in memory for later use. So you need to do more in your command.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, that is a pretty pointless command that deserves to fail!

It loads an image from disk and orientates it according to the metadata. It then strips the metadata, pointlessly stores the result in RAM (where it will be discarded after the program exits), then tells ImageMagick to delete the image from its list of images and exit, whereupon the RAM-based image is discarded. No point at all.

I guess the purpose is to re-save the picture with the correct orientation on top of the original file maybe...? If so, you could use:

```
convert image.png -auto-orient -strip image.png
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually this is not my code. It is from im-resize node module. I am curious this works fine on one of my ubuntu server but it doesn't work on another.

Comment: Both versions you mention are around 4+ years old. Things have changed a lot in the intervening years!